# How do I check if a directory exists in a jenkins pipeline?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have this small pipeline stage that uses the `script sh` to check to see if a directory exists

```
        stage("Check if Module exists") {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "ls -la && pwd"
                    sh "[ -d '"${env.SOURCE_REPO}"/"${env.COMPONENT_NAME}"' ]"
                    
                    repo_Check()
                }
            }
        }
```

Im using 2 env variables to create the full path of a directory. What is the correct syntax for this statement?

Comment: You can use the [fileExists](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace) step:  `if (fileExists("${env.SOURCE_REPO}/${env.COMPONENT_NAME}")){ ... }`